# How to set DPI information in an image?

Tags: java, image

I have an application that I want to export high-resolution (or rather, high pixel density?) images for printing - for example, I want images that print at 250 dots per inch (DPI), instead of the default, which I understand to be 72 DPI.

I'm using a BufferedImage with a Graphics2D object to draw the image, then ImageIO.write() to save the image.

Any idea how I can set the DPI?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Kurt's answer showed the way, still it took me quite some time to get it run, so here is the code that sets DPI when saving a PNG. There is a lot to do to get the proper writers and such...

```
 private BufferedImage gridImage;
 ...

 private void saveGridImage(File output) throws IOException {
    output.delete();

    final String formatName = "png";

    for (Iterator<ImageWriter> iw = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(formatName); iw.hasNext();) {
       ImageWriter writer = iw.next();
       ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
       ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);
       if (metadata.isReadOnly() || !metadata.isStandardMetadataFormatSupported()) {
          continue;
       }

       setDPI(metadata);

       final ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
       try {
          writer.setOutput(stream);
          writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(gridImage, null, metadata), writeParam);
       } finally {
          stream.close();
       }
       break;
    }
 }

 private void setDPI(IIOMetadata metadata) throws IIOInvalidTreeException {

    // for PMG, it's dots per millimeter
    double dotsPerMilli = 1.0 * DPI / 10 / INCH_2_CM;

    IIOMetadataNode horiz = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalPixelSize");
    horiz.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));

    IIOMetadataNode vert = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalPixelSize");
    vert.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));

    IIOMetadataNode dim = new IIOMetadataNode("Dimension");
    dim.appendChild(horiz);
    dim.appendChild(vert);

    IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_1.0");
    root.appendChild(dim);

    metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_1.0", root);
 }
```

Comment: why is it called grid image? anything different from a regular image?

Comment: @Zeveso I just happened to copy/paste this code from a working application that was saving an image of a grid, thus the name of the BufferedImage and the method. The code works for every BufferedImage.

Comment: @PeterKofler i am using above code without any changes. the above code creates PNG file as expected (using given dpi) but when i use above code for JPEG file it fails, do i need to set any parameter for JPEG or this code works only for PNG ?

Comment: @Mihir I am not aware of any problem JPG would have. Can you be more specific how it fails?

Comment: @PeterKofler when i save jpeg with 400 dpi using above code by seeting formatName = "jpg" it saves the file , but when i open the saved file in irfanview , photoshop , inkspace all shos the file's dpi 72 DPI.if you need i can ask a separate question with related screen shots on SO.

Comment: @Mihir , did you get anywhere with that?

Comment: @Mihir Check out my answer for a variation of the above code that works with JPG: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39994920/261142

Comment: I used same but I am getting 72 dpi only

Answer (score 4):

## Seting up TIFF DPI

If you want to set dpi for TIFF, try to do that by next steps:

```
private static IIOMetadata createMetadata(ImageWriter writer, ImageWriteParam writerParams, int resolution) throws
                                                                                                            IIOInvalidTreeException
{
    // Get default metadata from writer
    ImageTypeSpecifier type = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    IIOMetadata meta = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(type, writerParams);

    // Convert default metadata to TIFF metadata
    TIFFDirectory dir = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata(meta);

    // Get {X,Y} resolution tags
    BaselineTIFFTagSet base = BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance();
    TIFFTag tagXRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_X_RESOLUTION);
    TIFFTag tagYRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION);

    // Create {X,Y} resolution fields
    TIFFField fieldXRes = new TIFFField(tagXRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, new long[][] { { resolution, 1 } });
    TIFFField fieldYRes = new TIFFField(tagYRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, new long[][] { { resolution, 1 } });

    // Add {X,Y} resolution fields to TIFFDirectory
    dir.addTIFFField(fieldXRes);
    dir.addTIFFField(fieldYRes);

    // Add unit field to TIFFDirectory (change to RESOLUTION_UNIT_CENTIMETER if necessary)
    dir.addTIFFField(new TIFFField(base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT), BaselineTIFFTagSet.RESOLUTION_UNIT_INCH));

    // Return TIFF metadata so it can be picked up by the IIOImage
    return dir.getAsMetadata();
}
```

Also, similar way you can setting up any TIFF tag.

Read more at the [source](http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2012-11-25/java/creating-a-tif-file-a-resolution-x-ppi-a-pdfbox-pdpage)

Comment: I think the code is not complete as it does not set the resolution unit, which is by default `RESOLUTION_UNIT_NONE`. In such case the reader/client should set ratio to 1/1, see [`TIFFImageWriter:1182`](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/blob/0feba94520cc9cb59c58167f3b13dd712f100bbc/src/main/java/com/github/jaiimageio/impl/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriter.java#L1182). Fix: `dir.addTIFFField(new TIFFField(base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT), BaselineTIFFTagSet.RESOLUTION_UNIT_INCH))`. Disclaimer: I am not TIFF expert.

Comment: @dma_k feel free to edit answer if your suggestion works. I'm not a TIFF expert too )

Comment: As an additional reference I provide a link to [`TiffImage:146`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/b5807a839ab5bc3725f1dc1924cb947e072e0a7c/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/codec/TiffImage.java#L146), where one can see that X/Y DPI are set to zero if resolution unit is "none" and hence iTextPDF library interprets the image as having no DPI set. What clients are known to work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

i am using this code for tiff file in my project and it works well..

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.jai.NullOpImage;
import javax.media.jai.OpImage;
import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageEncoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFEncodeParam;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFField;
class SetDDPI
 {
static void tiff_Maker(List<BufferedImage> output, String result) throws   IOException
{
    TIFFEncodeParam params = new TIFFEncodeParam();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(result);
    List<BufferedImage> imageList = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    for (int i = 1; i < output.size(); i++)
    {
        imageList.add(output.get(i));
    }
    params.setWriteTiled(true);
    params.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_GROUP4);
    params.setExtraImages(imageList.iterator());
    TIFFField[] extras = new TIFFField[2];
    extras[0] = new TIFFField(282, TIFFField.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, (Object) new long[][] { { (long) 300, (long) 1 },
            { (long) 0, (long) 0 } });
    extras[1] = new TIFFField(283, TIFFField.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, (Object) new long[][] { { (long) 300, (long) 1 },
            { (long) 0, (long) 0 } });
    params.setExtraFields(extras);
    ImageEncoder encoder = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("tiff", out, params);
    encoder.encode(output.get(0));
    out.close();
}
static List<BufferedImage> tiff_Extractor(File tiff) throws IOException
{
    List<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    SeekableStream ss = new FileSeekableStream(tiff);
    ImageDecoder decoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", ss, null);
    int numPages = decoder.getNumPages();
    for (int j = 0; j < numPages; j++)
    {
        PlanarImage op = new NullOpImage(decoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(j), null, null, OpImage.OP_IO_BOUND);
        images.add(op.getAsBufferedImage());

    }
    return images;
}
}
```

this is to set 300 DPI of Tiff image. you can change it according to your need.

```
extras[0] = new TIFFField(282, TIFFField.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, (Object) new     
long[][] { { (long) 300, (long) 1 },{ (long) 0, (long) 0 } });

extras[1] = new TIFFField(283, TIFFField.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, (Object) new     
long[][] { { (long) 300, (long) 1 },{ (long) 0, (long) 0 } });
```

Comment: Dude you don't know how much help this provided ... Thank you very much for sharing this !!

Comment: That works great to set DPI but how do I set the resolution?

Comment: @rj27 I tried the above code from tiff_maker to set dpi for a bufferedImage I have and then I try saving it to the local fs `writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), null);`. After that I try to fetch the image and i get a gray screen with a size that is very large. Is there something I am missing?