# How to export high resolution image in Java

Tags: java, swing, screen-capture

I tried to take a snapshot of a JFrame and then export the image.  The DPI was only 72dpi, and I would like to know how to increase the resolution.

I followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321736/how-to-set-dpi-information-in-an-image) to set DPI of an image, but it does not really export a higher quality image...  It seems to only change the meta-data of the image file, not actually increase the quality of the export.

How can I export the image with an actual higher resolution then 72 dpi?

Answer (score 2):

The DPI metadata is just guidance as to the 'ideal' printing resolution/size of the image. As you say, it has nothing to do with the actual 'quality' of the image itself.

The snapshot *should* capture the actual full resolution of the JFrame (how did you capture the snapshot?). That's the maximum resolution that is possible -it's what Java generates and your monitor displays. There isn't anything else!

If the image quality appears poor, check you aren't saving it in a lossy format such as JPEG, though.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Robot.createScreenCapture() to get entire frame... The quality of export image is not bad. I just want to increase the resolution so that when I zoom out to larger size it should still maintain the high quality...

Comment: You can't zoom a bitmap past 100% and get any more quality - it's the fundamental nature of a bitmap!

Comment: (OK, there are some ways to cheat with interpolating photos, using fractal techniques, but those don't apply for crisp computer window graphics)