# How to set Dots Per Square Inch (DPI) for PNG in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, png, stack-overflow, dpi

Let me start off with I have no code and I have no idea what I am suppose to do. Apparently the information is stored in the meta data of the .png file. I figure this should not be so hard to do, but it is turning out to be a challenge.

The only thing that looks somewhat useful is the following post here at stack overflow.

[How to set DPI information in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321736/how-to-set-dpi-information-in-an-image)

However I have tried to use the code that was provided and the websites that were provided to do such things and have achieved nothing.

When I try to use the Iterator, like below, I get an error with both the iw.hasNext() and the iw.next().

Errors are:

- The method hasNext() is undefined for the type HTMLDocument.Iterator
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to ImageWriter

  for (Iterator iw = (Iterator) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(formatName); iw.hasNext;) {
    ImageWriter writer = iw.next();

**My question is, where do I start and what do I need to be looking for? Are there any examples that you know of or have you done this yourself?**

---

One a side note my questions about the "How to set DPI information in an image?" post are this...

1. Why is it then when I use the Iterator like he does, I get errors?
2. What is "INCH_2_CM" suppose to mean / be?

The way I changed his code is below...

---

```
    for (Iterator iw = (Iterator) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(formatName); iw.hasNext();) {
       ImageWriter writer = iw.next();
       ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
       ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);
       if (metadata.isReadOnly() || !metadata.isStandardMetadataFormatSupported()) {
          continue;
       }

       setDPI(metadata);

       final ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
       try {
          writer.setOutput(stream);
          writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(gridImage, null, metadata), writeParam);
       } finally {
          stream.close();
       }
       break;
    }
```

Comment: INCH_2_CM is probably a `final` variable equal to 2.54, the multiplication constant to convert a length in inches to its value in centimeters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is getting confused between the classes `javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator` and `java.util.Iterator`.  His code uses the latter, but your code seems to be using the former.  Use fully qualified types, or figure out how to modify your imports.

Comment: You are right, I feel like an idiot. How did you figure that out without me showing my imports?

Comment: It was pretty clear from `The method hasNext() is undefined for the type HTMLDocument.Iterator`.

Comment: In all honesty, a poor decision on the designer of that library, knowing the possible confusion down the road. Chances are, they expected people to simply use enhanced for loops instead of Iterators.

Comment: @corsiKa: you're right, it was a dumb naming decision.  The decision predated enhanced for loops, so there's no excuse.  I always get bitten by `java.util.List` and `java.awt.List`.