# Failed to change exported image DPI

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am currently working on a project which export PDF to a series of high quality images.
So far I can export the images, but the quality I got is not very good. I have read the solution of similar question and tried it out myself but it doesn't work

Here's my code, I have included the code required to export PDF to image in case you may want to test/find out my errors in the coding

```
//Load pdf from path(file)
    File file = new File("C:\\TEMP\\office\\a.pdf");
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    byte[] b = new byte[(int) raf.length()];
    raf.readFully(b);
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
    PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);

    //Get number of pages
    int numOfPages = pdffile.getNumPages();
    // Only in this case, I have "hardcoded" 4 in get page just because I wanted a 1-page sample
    PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(4);
    //Create new image, according to the rectangle area
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)page.getPageBox().getX(), (int)page.getPageBox().getY(), (int) page.getBBox().getWidth(), (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());
    Image img = page.getImage(rect.width, rect.height, rect, null, true, true);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(rect.width, rect.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    File asd = new File("C:\\TEMP\\office\\img\\Testingx" + 4 + ".png");

    //This is the method provided by answer in the reference link, 
    saveGridImage(asd, bufferedImage);
    //The method header of saveGridImage is modified to saveGridImage(File output,BufferedImage gridImage)
```

However, the exported image simply same as before, the text on the images "blurred"

My Question: Is there somethings wrong with my program? Am I doing it the wrong way?

Related Reference: [Set DPI Info in Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321736/how-to-set-dpi-information-in-an-image)

Library used in the program: [PDFRenderer](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer)

Sample PDF used to test quality: [[PDF]
PUBLIC DOCUMENTATION LICENSE Version 1.0](http://www.openoffice.org/licenses/pdl.pdf)

Comment: Did you debug and check if the setDpi method is getting called or not?

Comment: Tested, It has been called

Comment: Are you sure that setting the DPI of the exported image (PNG is a pixel based format) matters at all here? I believe that if the text looks blurred, it's because the PDF is not rendered at the correct resolution (yet). Beware that `Image` (as opposed to `BufferedImage`) allows for multi-pass rendering, so also verify that `page.getImage` returns a fully rendered image.

Comment: page.getImage(.. , .. , .. , .. , .. , true); This ensured the method only return the image until the image is fully rendered