# How to Create a high resolution image (jpg gif or png) from screen (150/300/600 dpi)

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am trying to create a screenshoot of a zone of my screen
I did some test and for  JPG file it always create a 96 dpi resolution image.

I tried  using  the technique described  in [How to set DPI information in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321736/how-to-set-dpi-information-in-an-image#comment21894953_4833697)   but it seems to only change the metadata of the image.

Thanks for help

edit 1 :  so I want to create a screenshot at a resolution higher than what my display is using. As  @Toam  said, the display is actually 96 DPI

Comment: If you are trying to take a screen shot you will be theoretically limited to the screen resolution, since that is how the image is being rendered. 96 DPI seems to be the standard (at least in Windows) for the display (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#Computer_monitor_DPI_standards) and that is what you are sampling when you take a screen shot.

Comment: Why would you want a 150,300,600 DPI image? All things are rendered in pixels

Comment: @JClassic , I mean 150 or 300 or 600 dpi

Comment: Oh XD ok. I though you mean 150 million

Comment: DPI *is* just metadata... Setting the DPI higher will not give you more detail or more pixels. Do you mean you want to create a screenshot with a higher resolution than what your display uses?

Comment: @haraldK Thats what I realize the DPI information is just metadata used to print the image to the printer..    And you are right , I want to create a screen resolution higher than my display is using ... So far it alays create at 96 dpi

Comment: @Toam  Thats exact the screen shot I create are always at 96 dpi.   But I want higher DPI,  do you known a way to achive this ??

Comment: The dpi of the image is purely dependent on its display size. It's not a property of the image. If you zoom in you decrease the dpi. Your screen probably can't physically display better than 96dpi (there aren't enough pixels).

Comment: "I tried using the technique described in How to set DPI information in an image? but it seems to only change the metadata of the image."  Well, yes.  You can print a 96 dpi screen image on a 600 dpi printer, and roughly 6 inches of screen image will print in one inch of paper.  You don't gain any pixels, unless you use a program to interpolate pixels.