# Adding Details into PNG/JPG/JPEG file with java

Tags: java, javafx, png

I create Image with ImageIO in java formatted Png/Jpg or Jpeg and scaled up into some Height and Width, My problem is in the import my image into AutoCad Going to be so small! the Image Have 7852*3719 px but in AutoCad is so small , I figure it out it's about Details that Image Have, Look at the Picture That can see the difference The Example Image Have Horizontal and Vertical Resolution and Created Image With ImageIO  in java Have'nt.

So How I can Add this details into My Image with Java?
[image]

The Part of my code that Create Image:

```
private void exportImageToFile(BufferedImage bufferedImage, boolean withHintText) {
        String ext = MeasurementsView.extImageType;
        fileName = "";
        ImageStone imageStone = sqliteRepo.getImageStone(imageIdForSaveIntoFile);
        if (imageIdForSaveIntoFile != 0) {
            fileName += imageStone.getName();
        } else {
            fileName += "" + (new Date().getTime());
        }
        fileName += "-" + ((int) getDpi()) + "dpi";
        if (withHintText) {
            fileName += "-hint";
        }
        FileChooser saveFile = new FileChooser();
        saveFile.setInitialFileName(fileName + (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("PNG") ? ".png" : ".jpg"));
        if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("PNG")) {
            saveFile.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("تصویر با فرمت (*.png)", "*.png"));
        } else {
            saveFile.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("تصویر با فرمت (*.jpg)", "*.jpg"));

        }
        File homeDir = new File(App.config.optString(App.ConfigElements.PATH_IMAGE) + File.separator + "Export" + File.separator);
        if (!homeDir.exists()) {
            try {
                homeDir.mkdirs();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                App.logger.error("can't create Export Folder.");
            }
        }
        if (!homeDir.canRead()) {
            homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        }
        if (!homeDir.canRead()) {
            homeDir = new File("c:/");
        }
        saveFile.setInitialDirectory(homeDir);
        saveFile.setTitle("خروجی مقیاس سنجی");
        File file = saveFile.showSaveDialog(canvas.getScene().getRoot().getScene().getWindow());
        if (file != null) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    App.logger.debug("Going to create Export With File : " + fileName);
                    BufferedImage scaleUpImage = scale(bufferedImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB,
                            (int) convertMMToPx(theWidthOfBondClipInMM()), (int) convertMMToPx(theHeightOfBondClipInMM())
                            , convertMMToPx(theWidthOfBondClipInMM()) / bufferedImage.getWidth()
                            , convertMMToPx(theHeightOfBondClipInMM()) / bufferedImage.getHeight());
                    if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("PNG")) {
                        ImageIO.write(scaleUpImage, "png", file);
                    } else {
                        ImageIO.write(scaleUpImage, "JPG", file);
                    }

                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    try {
                        desktop.open(file);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        App.logger.fatal("Ops! look at this fatal error in opening the file explorer: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    App.logger.error("Save Export Jump to IOException:" + ex.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    loadingBarForMes.setVisible(false);
                }
            }).start();

        } else {
            loadingBarForMes.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

Also is good to know the answer of this [How to set DPI information in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321736/how-to-set-dpi-information-in-an-image) it's not the answer I looking for because this method nothing add into Properties of file and Details.